# Licensing issue

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a .NET application that is storing information in an sql server database.

I wanna add licensing to my app to only allow a certain number of items in the DB depending on the license.
So say, for example, that i have an "items" table and the license is for 5000 items.

The problem i'm facing is that i can't rely on my app not inserting the item if the table row count is > 5000, because the user can insert items directly into the DB since **the server is provided by the customer so he will have full unrestricted access to the DB. (i can't use any sql server-side solutions as well due to this particular issue)**

Also, if i add a field to the table that i fill with the item info hashed with a password then the user can no longer add items manually but then i'll have to run through the whole table and check whether each item is licensed and count licensed items before determining whether to add each new item or not. This is not practical since i receive hundreds of items per minute so it will greatly affect performance.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you thought about restricting the software in a different way.  Beyond simply knowing how many rows there are, and simply not allowing the application to function if there are more then 5,000 items I don't see a way.  Honestly you cannot have both "allow the user to manually add items" and "prevent the user from adding items after he reaches the 5,000 limit".

Comment: I don't want users to manually add items but the problem is that the users will also have access to the DB since sometimes i install the app on their servers.

Comment: If you receive 100's of items a minute, wouldn't your license only be valid for about 50 minutes then? Are you **sure** this is the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the restriction upside down and limit your queries to 5000 results. This can be easily done with the [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) clause.

This way it doesn't matter how many rows the user shoves into the database, your program will only work with the ones it's licenced to.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet might be an [INSTEAD OF trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917664.aspx) on the `Items` table to reject inserts beyond your limit.

Comment: The users will have access to the DB since it's their own server and even sometimes their own sql instance so sadly, i can't use any method on the sql side.

Comment: @ElArZ if the user has total control over the DB, there is not a lot you can do.  There is trickery they could do to counteract almost anything you could do on the client side.  They could replace the table with a view and then swap in and out portions of an underlying table at will.

Comment: @ElArZ, why don't you make this 'INSTEAD OF' trigger and make a mirror of it on the code. If the super user alter or delete the trigger, you will be able to compare it with the code one and restrict the access , re-create the trigger or simply throw an invalid operation and shut the program

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend a simple trigger (which you can base on a configuration table if you want).

I'd like to know a little more about the overall business requirements, since it seems like the table would fill up in under an hour if you are receiving hundreds of rows a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I would decouple the license validation from your DL all together. Instead have your app run a its validation script at some point and then take the required (disabling/warnig) action  if validation fails.

Something like this should return very quickly:

`SELECT 
    [TableName] = so.name, 
    [RowCount] = MAX(si.rows) 
FROM 
    sysobjects so, 
    sysindexes si 
WHERE 
    so.xtype = 'U' 
    AND 
    si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name) 
GROUP BY 
    so.name 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC`